# When adding firebase analystcs library giving a unexcepted error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

This is my **Build.gradle** code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stars.vk.fileshare"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        
    }
    
    buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

dependencies {
    
    // Do Not change in these dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

And I have my all classes but this is error when i am open app.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.stars.vk.fileshare, PID: 29184
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/stars/vk/fileshare/PrimaryHandle;
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.stars.vk.fileshare.HomeActivity.Widgets(HomeActivity.java:223)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.stars.vk.fileshare.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:101)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.stars.vk.fileshare.PrimaryHandle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.stars.vk.fileshare-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 15 more
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stars.vk.fileshare.PrimaryHandle
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 16 more
09-30 19:41:05.176 29184 29184 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Please help me.
I am confused.

and **Another** can i use firebase **Remote Config** without this firebase analystics library because when i remove it then there is no problems.
Firebase also not confirming that my app have installed library when i remove it library.
Can you suggest me some tricks about these.

Comment: It's better to call out specific versions of dependencies than using +.

Comment: It is using lestet version of library and it is not matter .